# Python: iterate through the rows of a csv and calculate date difference if there is a change in a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, datetime, iteration

Only basic knowledge of Python, so I'm not even sure if this is possible?

I have a csv that looks like this:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8clYM.png
(This is dummy data, the real one is about 30K rows.)
I need to **find the most recent job title** for each employee (unique id) and then **calculate how long** (= how many days) the employee has been on the same job title.

What I have done so far:

```
import csv
import datetime
from datetime import *

data = open("C:\\Users\\User\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\jts.csv",encoding="utf-8")
csv_data  = csv.reader(data)
data_lines = list(csv_data)
print(data_lines)

for i in data_lines:
    for j in i[0]:
```

But then I haven't got anywhere because I can't even conceptualise how to structure this. :-(
I also know that at one point I will need:

```
datetime.strptime(data_lines[1][2] , '%Y/%M/%d').date()
```

Could somebody help, please? I just need a new list saying something like:
id  jt      days
500 plumber 370

Edit to clarify: The dates are data points taken. I need to calculate back from the most recent of those back until the job title was something else. So in my example for employee 5000 from 04/07/2021 to 01/03/2020.

Comment: I would just like to say 'thank you' to you all who have written code for me to solve my problem; and thus have helped me learn. Appreciate your kindness. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider sample data as follows:

```
id,jtitle,date
5000,plumber,01/01/2020
5000,senior plumber,02/03/2020
6000,software engineer,01/02/2020
6000,software architecture,06/02/2021
7000,software tester,06/02/2019
```

The following code works.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# load data
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# convert to datetime object
data.date = pd.to_datetime(data.date, dayfirst=True)
print(data)

# group employees by ID
latest = data.sort_values('date', ascending=False).groupby('id').nth(0)
print(latest)

# find the latest point in time where there is a change in job title
prev_date = data.sort_values('date', ascending=False).groupby('id').nth(1).date
print(prev_date)

# calculate the difference in days
latest['days'] = latest.date - prev_date
print(latest)
```

Output:

```
             jtitle         date           days
id                                             
5000         senior plumber 2020-03-02  61 days
6000  software architecture 2021-02-06 371 days
7000        software tester 2019-02-06      NaT
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the trouble to write the answer. I probably haven't phrased the question right and so the code does not answer my problem. :-( The date next to the record is when the data point was taken. I need the elapsed time (in days) not from today but from the most recent data point back to when the job title changed, ie. the data point when the job title was something else. I.e. in my example for employee 5000 from 04/07/2021 to 01/03/2020

Comment: I modified the code to align with your requirement. Note that if there is only one record for an employee (e.g., 7000), then `NaT` is returned.

Comment: You are amazing, @lenhhoxung! Thank you so much. It's perfect - you have saved me an enormous amount of manual work and I could have never done it myself! Also thank you for the concise commenting in the code, that's just brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

> But then I haven't got anywhere because I can't even conceptualise how to structure this. :-(

Have a map (dict) of employee to (date, title).

For every row, check if you already have an entry for the employee. If you don't just put the information in the map, otherwise compare the date of the row and that of the entry. If the row has a more recent date, replace the entry.

Once you've gone through all the rows, you can just go through the map you've collected and compute the difference between the date you ended up with and "today".

Incidentally your pattern is not correct, the sample data uses a `%d/%m/%Y` (day/month/year) or `%m/%d/%Y` (month/day/year) format, the sample data is not sufficient to say which, but it certainly is not YMD.

Comment: thank you for pointing out the mistake in the pattern; and also for putting into words what needs to be done. I am not a scientist by training and have trouble to get my head around what steps need to be taken.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I'm too late... Nevertheless, in case you're interested, here's a suggestion in pure Python (nothing wrong with Pandas, though!):

```
import csv
import datetime as dt
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

reader = csv.reader('data.csv')
next(reader) # Discard header row
# Read, transform (date), and sort in reverse (id first, then date):
data = sorted(((i, jtitle, dt.datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y'))
               for i, jtitle, date in reader),
              key=itemgetter(0, 2), reverse=True)

# Process data grouped by id
result = []
for i, group in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0)):
    _, jtitle, end = next(group)  # Fetch last job title resp. date

    # Search for first ocurrence of different job title:
    start = end
    for _, jt, start in group:
        if jt != jtitle:
            break

    # Collect results in list with datetimes transformed back
    result.append((i, jtitle, end.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'), (end - start).days)) 

result = sorted(result, key=itemgetter(0))
```

The result for the input data

```
id,jtitle,date
5000,plumber,01/01/2020
5000,plumber,01/02/2020
5000,senior plumber,01/03/2020
5000,head plumber,01/05/2020
5000,head plumber,02/09/2020
5000,head plumber,05/01/2021
5000,head plumber,04/07/2021
6000,electrician,01/02/2018
6000,qualified electrician,01/06/2020
7000,plumber,01/01/2004
7000,plumber,09/11/2020
7000,senior plumber,05/06/2021
```

is

```
[('5000', 'head plumber', '04/07/2021', 490),
 ('6000', 'qualified electrician', '01/06/2020', 851),
 ('7000', 'senior plumber', '05/06/2021', 208)]
```

Comment: thank you very much for this: I have been looking for a base python solution because I feel that I have more chance to understand how it works. (I know nothing of pandas.) I greatly appreciate you taking the time to work this out for me and comment it, too. I am going to save your solution among my notes and go through it to learn.